# when i set @media between 600~767,100~599 there is missing on 599.xx

Tags: css, media-queries

Now I'm learning about CSS
when I type like this

```
.pc{
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .pc {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    .pc {
        color: green;
        font-size: 10px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
}
```

for example

in the 599.XXXpx (599.123, 599.284)

At this point

the color is go back to red and pink

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Most of browsers will not display fraction pixel. A pixel is a smallest unit to display. So you do need to be worry about the breakpoint you mentioned. It is not phisically happens.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, I would recommend you to use the same number for both media queries, and then order the rules so the one that you want to win goes later.

If you would like to keep it blue and yellow, then you will have to change the order of the rules:

```css
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 600px) { /* … */ }
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px) { /* … */ }
```

But if you'd like to keep the green and gray colors, keep the current order:

```css
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px) { /* … */ }
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 600px) { /* … */ }
```